# Capacitor Custom AVPlayer View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, capacitor

I'm new to Swift / iOS, so my apologies if I may come across as daft. I am trying to play a custom video splashscreen for my capacitor iOS app on launch, but I seem to be having troubles switching view controllers using segues. On my Main storyboard, I have two View Controllers, the Capacitor Bridge View (which runs my react app perfectly fine), and I have an AVPlayer View Controller.

I have set my AVPlayer as the Initial View Controller and created a segue to the capacitor bridge view with the segue having id "test", and I call a performsegue() method in the custom AVPlayer controller at the end of the video, which doesn't do anything, despite it running.

Here is the custom class for my AVPlayer

```
//
//  AVPlayer.swift
//  App
//
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import Capacitor


class viewControl: AVPlayerViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            playVideo()
        }
        
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        private func playVideo() {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Splash_Screen_Christmas", ofType:"mp4") else {
                debugPrint("splash.m4v not found")
                return
            }
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
            playerController.player = player
            playerController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerController.player?.currentItem)
            present(playerController, animated: true) {
                player.play()
            }
        }
        @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
           // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            // let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "test", sender: self)
            print("Method, video is finished ")
        }
    
    
}
```

After the video plays, the simulator logs "video is finished" but the Bridge View Controller is not being pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by avoiding using a separate view controllers, for anyone using Capacitor to add a new view controller, you will need to switch view controllers by creating a subclass of the CAPBridgeViewController

```
import UIKit
import Capacitor
import AVKit
// Instantiate a subclass of CAPBridgeViewController

class capController: CAPBridgeViewController {
    // Define video URL here
    let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Splash_Screen_Normal", ofType:"mp4")!))
    
      var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillAppear(animated)

          playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
          playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
          playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
          view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
          // Try catch to avoid breaking user background audio.
          do {
              try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: .mixWithOthers)
                  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
             } catch {
                  print(error)
             }
          // End of background audio code validation
          player.play()
          NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
      }

      @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
          print("Video has finished running.")
          playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
      }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```